# How do I make a delay between when a sensor is activated and when the controller activates?

Tags: game-engine, objects, physics, scene

So I've been working on this car game and want the level to restart when you hit the ground outside the track.

I have a collision sensor on the car looking for colliding with an object with the property "Ground" Next, I have that running through an and controller into a scene actuator that restarts the level.

The problem is that the level restarts as soon as you hit the ground outside the track. How do i add a delay between the collision sensor and the scene actuator?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. An event already happened. What you do is to describe the operations on the event.

But you can lift it to an higher abstraction level. Split the logic into two parts:

- on collision start a timer
- on timeout switch the scene

Reference:

- [How do you add a cool down timer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58215/how-do-you-add-a-cool-down-timer/58251#58251)